# Finding similar quantum superposition pairs

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, quantum-states

I am not sure if my thinking is correct and I'd like to ask if someone can confirm it, or give explanation, what am I doing wrong. I did task where I was asked to tell if pairs of expressions for quantum states represent the same state.

Two samples I've been thinking about:

1. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert m\rangle+\lvert u\rangle)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert m\rangle-\lvert u\rangle)$
2. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert m\rangle-\lvert u\rangle)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert u\rangle-\lvert m\rangle)$

What I've learned so far is that those two superpositions should have equal relative phase which is the modulus one complex number $e^{i\phi}$ satisfying $\frac{a}{b}= e^{i\phi}\frac{\lvert a\rvert}{\lvert b \rvert}$ so they can be similar.

If my understanding is correct example $1$ shows similar states, because even though there is different sign, modulus value is equal. As for the number $2$ sign is the same, but the order is different, so they are not similar.

Is that correct?

Comment: In example 1. the states are orthogonal, therefore different. In example 2. the states differ only by a global phase, so they are the same.

Comment: @MarkMitchison My mistake, yes you are right. I've checked it again. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this rigorously use the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). If we call your two states $\psi$ and $\chi$, then the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality tells us that:

$$\lvert\langle \psi \vert \chi \rangle\rvert^2 \leq \langle \psi\vert\psi\rangle\langle\chi\vert\chi\rangle $$

And in particular we get equality if and only if $\chi$ and $\psi$ are linearly dependent i.e. the same state give or take an overall multiplier.

If we take your first pair:

$$\begin{align}
\psi &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert m\rangle+\lvert u\rangle) \\
\chi &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert m\rangle-\lvert u\rangle)
\end{align} $$

Then assuming $\lvert m\rangle$ and $\lvert u\rangle$ are orthonormal we get:

$$\begin{align}
\langle\psi\lvert\chi\rangle = 0 \\
\langle\psi\lvert\psi\rangle = 1 \\
\langle\chi\lvert\chi\rangle = 1
\end{align} $$

So in this case the two states are different. I'll leave you to do the calculation for the second pair.